# encapsulation of a sub-namespace in c#

Tags: c#, namespaces, encapsulation

I have a class library project. In this project i have some folders to seperate the logic.

Lets say i have a **DAL** library and within DAL i have **IDAL**, **DALFactory** and **SQLServerDAL**.
Now when i give DAL dll to an other programmer, he can use all of the subDlls. Suppose that i dont want him to use SQLServerDal but others. How can i encapsulate SQLServerDAL so that noone can realize it exists.

Thanks. 
**EDIT:**
More spesically:

```
using DAL; // it can be written
using DAL.IDAL; // it can be written
using DAL.DALFactory; // it can be written
using DAL.SQLServerDAL; // it dont want to allow anyone write that
```

Comment: Why? What would the use of that be? If you simply do not distribute that implementation, others will not know it exists. If you do, reflection can easily find it (or tools like resharper).

Comment: Are you looking for the internal specifier, specifically for restricting access to inside the assembly?  [internal c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.80).aspx)  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: internal specifier hides only classes which you mark as internal. But users can still see SQLServerDAL namespace. i just wonder if it is possible.

Comment: If all of the contents of the SQLServerDAL folder are marked as internal, then the namespace is not publicly visible either.

Comment: @MarcArmstrong i tried that but it didnt get any effect. i changed every classes to internal in SQLServerDAL, but SQLServerDAL is still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to do with namespaces, because they don't exist on the metadata level. Either make all classes in namespace SQLServerDAL internal, as suggested by others, or make SQLServerDAL a static internal class instead of a namespace. In this approach classes inside SQLServerDAL will become nested classes, and will be inaccessible from outside your DAL assembly:

```
// what you have now:
namespace DAL.SQLServerDal
{
    public class A {}
    public class B {}
}

// in other assembly
using DAL.SQLServerDal ; // ok
new A () ; // ok

// with internal classes:
namespace DAL.SQLServerDal
{
    internal class A {}
    internal class B {}
}

// in other assembly
using DAL.SQLServerDal ; // ok
new A () ;               // error: A is inaccessible due to protection level

// what I propose:
namespace DAL
{
    internal static class SQLServerDal
    {
        public class A {}
        public class B {}
    }
}

// in other assembly
using DAL.SQLServerDal ; // error: namespace DAL.SQLServerDal does not exist
```

However, if you use reflection or code generation, you may have problems if the libraries you are using do not support nested classes properly.

Comment: so you mean that it is impossible to hide DAL.SQLServerDAL namespace unless i change the classes as static? if it is the case i think i will prefer giving up hiding this assembly. i dont want to make my classes as static.

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to hide a namespace, but there are other options — see update.

Comment: Yeah you advice changing the classes to internal **static**. This will do what i need however i do not want static classes. if @BitKFu sends his recommendation i will look over it. And if it is not stutable i will just let my namespace visible to others.

Comment: i think your approach is the most pleasant way to achive my goal. However i dont want to use any static class on that. So, i will let the assambly be visible. It wont be much harmfull. You can also see answer of @BitKFu. It is also usefull but nasty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an optimal solution but:-

Change the SQLServerDAL classes to internal. Then in the properties/assemblyinfo.cs file add for any DLLs that require access to the SQLServerDAL:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Fully.Qualified.AssemblyName")]
```

This obviously doesn't protect against dissambling, but it won't publicly visible by anyone consuming your dll.

Comment: SQLServerDAL is still visible within other libraries.

Comment: then you haven't made it internal

Comment: @AdamRalph i have made all the **classes** internal. For instance, suppose there is a subfoler named SQLServerDAL. And in this folder i have Customers class. i can only make Customers as internal so i did it. And programmers can not see Customers class because it is internal. That is ok until now. But programmers can still add **using DAL.SQLServerDAL;** statement although they can not find any public class in it. i simply dont want them to see that there is a subfolder named SQLServerDAL within DAL library.

Comment: unfortunately, AFAIK, that is not possible

Comment: Fer: anyone can use Reflector or ildasm and see all your code and metadata anyway. The only real remedy for that is obfuscating your code.

Answer (score 0):

What are these 'sub DLLs' of which you speak?

> I have a class library project.

From this I assume you have a single DLL. In that case, there is no such thing as a 'sub DLL'. The classes defined in sub-folders of your project are part of that single DLL. The fact that they are in sub-folders makes no difference whatsoever. If you have added the sub-folder name to the namespace of each class, all this means is that the names of the resulting types will include the name of the folder in them.

If you want to make certain types internal, use the [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword. Unfortunately there is no way to make *all* classes under a given sub-folder internal. If you want to do that, you will need to add the `internal` keyword to *each* class definition in the sub-folder.

Comment: yes there is no sub-dlls i meant sub-folders. However you know it can be used with using statement like a dll. For ex. **using DAL.SQLServerDAL;** At this point, i dont want anyone can even put it in using list.

Comment: ok - so in that case make the class internal - see the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can add the DLL that you want to hide as a resource file in your parent project. Therefore you have to add the compiled DLL and mark it as "Embedded Resource" in the solution.

Second step is to load the DLL within your parent libarary in order to access it.

```
Stream stream = GetType().Assembly
               .GetManifestResourceStream("<<FULL QUALIFIED DLL NAME>>");
if (stream == null)
    throw new InvalidDataException("<<FULL QUALIFIED DLL NAME>> not found.");

byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int) stream.Length);

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(buffer);
```

After you have the assembly reference, you can work on getting the classes and methods you want to access.

```
var sqlServerDAL = assembly.GetType("<<FULL QUALIFIED CLASS NAME>>");
var method = sqlServerDAL.GetMethod("<<METHOUD>>", BindingFlags.Public);
```

I know that this is a really nasty way to obfuscate some classes, but it's effective. Because the DLL is not in the directory, nor you can simple type the namespace to access the classes.

Comment: Hello BitKFu. i have already marked all classes as internal. But the case is not classes, it is assambly. SQLServerDAL is a subfolder within DAL library. Althought all the classes are internal in SQLServerDAL folder(DAL.SQLServerDAL Namespace), people still can referance DAL.SQLServerDAL namespace in their using list. i tried to explain in response to comment of @AdamRalph

Comment: ok ;) I have a solution for you which I used in another project. But I don't have the code at hand. The primary thought is to put the DLL into the resource of the first DLL and load it from the embedded resources. I'm going to send you the code in the evening, If you do not find a solution until then.

Comment: Yes i would like to see your solution. it may help and we can share it here too and discuss about it.

Comment: Thank you for your edit showing the way you do this. as you mentioned it is really nasty way. So i think i will just let it be visible. I have come to know that there is no non-nasty way of hiding DAL.SQLServerDAL in my case unless i prefer to use static approach as @AntonTykhyy advised. Thank you indeed